# After update the ADT, the testing app (phonegap) can't run

Tags: android, cordova

i'm learning phonegap, before updated the ADT, the apps run well, here is the index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" /> 
        <script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="page_dashboard">

         <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scripts/dashboard.js"></script>

         <div data-role="header">
           <h1>Dashboard</h1>
         </div><!-- /header -->

         <div data-role="content">
           <p><a href="#page_login" data-role="button" id="button_login">Login</a></p>
           <p><a href="#" data-role="button" id="button_logout">Logout</a></p>
         </div><!-- /content -->

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is the .java

```
package com.hkinterview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class hkinterview extends DroidGap
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Error:

```
    05-30 07:27:49.223: E/AndroidRuntime(934): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 07:27:49.223: E/AndroidRuntime(934): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.hkinterview/com.hkinterview.hkinterview}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.hkinterview.hkinterview" on path: /data/app/com.hkinterview-2.apk
05-30 07:27:49.223: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
05-30 07:27:49.223: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-30 07:27:49.223: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-30 07:27:49.223: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-30 07:27:49.223: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-30 07:27:49.223: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-30 07:27:49.223: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-30 07:27:49.223: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 07:27:49.223: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-30 07:27:49.223: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-30 07:27:49.223: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-30 07:27:49.223: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-30 07:27:49.223: E/AndroidRuntime(934): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.hkinterview.hkinterview" on path: /data/app/com.hkinterview-2.apk
05-30 07:27:49.223: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
05-30 07:27:49.223: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-30 07:27:49.223: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-30 07:27:49.223: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
05-30 07:27:49.223: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
05-30 07:27:49.223: E/AndroidRuntime(934):  ... 11 more
05-30 07:31:17.932: E/Trace(992): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-30 07:31:18.074: W/dalvikvm(992): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/hkinterview/hkinterview; (15)
05-30 07:31:18.123: W/dalvikvm(992): Link of class 'Lcom/hkinterview/hkinterview;' failed
05-30 07:31:18.123: D/AndroidRuntime(992): Shutting down VM
05-30 07:31:18.132: W/dalvikvm(992): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-30 07:31:18.154: E/AndroidRuntime(992): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 07:31:18.154: E/AndroidRuntime(992): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.hkinterview/com.hkinterview.hkinterview}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.hkinterview.hkinterview" on path: /data/app/com.hkinterview-1.apk
05-30 07:31:18.154: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
05-30 07:31:18.154: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-30 07:31:18.154: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-30 07:31:18.154: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-30 07:31:18.154: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-30 07:31:18.154: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-30 07:31:18.154: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-30 07:31:18.154: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 07:31:18.154: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-30 07:31:18.154: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-30 07:31:18.154: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-30 07:31:18.154: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-30 07:31:18.154: E/AndroidRuntime(992): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.hkinterview.hkinterview" on path: /data/app/com.hkinterview-1.apk
05-30 07:31:18.154: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
05-30 07:31:18.154: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-30 07:31:18.154: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-30 07:31:18.154: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
05-30 07:31:18.154: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
05-30 07:31:18.154: E/AndroidRuntime(992):  ... 11 more
```

---------------------manifest----------------------

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="hkinterview" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@hkinterview

I had similar problem and I solved it as user1971705 mentioned.

1. Right Click on you r Project - > Properties
2. Click on Java Build Path in left Pane
3. Click on the 'Order and Export' tab in the right pane
4. Make Sure 'Android Private Libraries' is checked
5. Hit Ok

Comment: Thank you! I have been fighting with this for hours and this finally did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Hi  are you adt version is  22,   Open the java build path , select the Order and Export ,
and check the  Android Private Libraries.  Adt22 can't add the libs library to the project if not select it

Comment: where is "Open the java build path , select the Order and Export"